# Use a php loop to process text and file inputs from html form

Tags: php, html

I am stuck on trying to make this work, I have a html form that has file and text inputs, after submission I want to process these inputs through a loop in my php script. Currently the loop skips the file input and processes only the text inputs. I am new at php, and I cant seem to understand what is wrong and how to fix it. Here is the form code and the php code to process it.

```
<form action='loop.php' enctype="multipart/form-data" data-ajax="false" method="POST">
     <input type ="text" name ="Input1"/>
     <input type ="file" name ="Input2"/>
     <input type ="text" name ="Input3"/>
     <input type ="text" name ="Input4"/>
     <input type='submit' data-corners="false" value ='submit'/>
</form>
```

loop.php

```
<?php
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
         if($_POST[Input2]) //check if its the file input
         {//some manipulation on the file}
         else
         //process all other text inputs}
?>
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: `files` are in `$_FILES`, and posted data is in `$_POST`.

Comment: I did not know that... Thanks. Using `$_FILES` i am now able to access the files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `$_POST[Input2]` is wrong, but it should work. That's because `Input2` is recognized as constant, not as string (what it should be). Change that into `$_POST['Input2']` (see also [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.foo-bar)).
2. You haven't closed some of the brackets. Pay attention to the legibility of your code to avoid this!
3. `$_POST[Input2]` doesn't check if the currently processed input is `Input2`. You should do this with `$key`.

Comment: `Currently the loop skips the file input and processes only the text inputs`. This is an issue with `$_FILES[]`, not an issue with his input constants. Good effort, though.